# ajax HTML content not rendering in bootstrap pop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get HTML content from an ajax request to load in a twitter bootstrap (v3) popover.

The popover element looks like this.

```
<a class="more-info" data-remotecontent="/tasks/moreinfo/56eb0256-1a78-483c-b053-a387011f5b97" data-original-title="task 1" data-title="task 1" data-toggle="popover" rel="popover" href="/tasks/56eb0256-1a78-483c-b053-a387011f5b97">task 1</a>
```

And the javascript looks like this.

```
$('a.more-info').each(function () {
            var info = $(this);
            info.bind('mouseenter', function () {
                info.popover({
                    html: true,
                    title: info.html(),
                    content: 'Loading',
                }).popover('show');

                $.get(info.attr('data-remotecontent'), function (data) {

                }).done(function (data) {
                    info.attr('data-html', 'true');
                    //info.popover({ content: data, placement: 'right' }).popover('show');
                    info.attr('data-placement', 'right');
                    info.attr('data-content', data);
                    info.popover('show');
                });



            });

            info.bind('mouseleave', function () {
                info.popover('hide');
            });
        });
```

The ajax get request returns HTML but it never gets rendered into the popover. I have a feeling I may not be escaping the response string properly.

What am I missing to get the ajax response rendered into the content of the popover?

Comment: I used the answer from @user3558931 . However for some reason my original HTML wasn't rendering. I had it in a popover template suggested by bootstrap's site. I re-wrote the HTML without the popover wrappers and HTML seems to be rendering properly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of a bootstrap method of injecting new content to a `popover` that's already initialized, you would have to manipulate the generated markup shown below. **This is not an ideal solution. I would recommend calling the `destroy` method once once the ajax content is received updating the element and initializing and programmatically opening the popover.**

**A. Manipulating the popover markup -- not good**

Here is how the popover markup looks like:

```
<div class="popover fade right" role="tooltip" ....>
    <div class="arrow" style="top: 12.987012987013%;"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">task 1</h3>
    <div class="popover-content">Loading</div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** *The main reason this is not a good solution is that there's no guarantee that this will be the markup in future versions.*

[**Concept Verification**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/567qr3mm/)

**B. Calling destroy method, initializing and opening -- GOOD**

[**Concept Verification**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/567qr3mm/3/)

In addition, your `mouseleave` handler would have to destroy the popover again and initialize it if you want each `mouseenter` event to produce the same `Loading ..` effect.

```
    info.bind('mouseleave', function () {
        info.popover('destroy')
        .popover({
            html: true,
            title: info.html(),
            content: 'Loading',
        });
    });
```

Comment: This works to a point.  The popover displays but the content of the popover is the unrendered html string. Something like "<div class="popover" role="tooltip">...</div>"

Comment: If you use `.popover({html:true})` instead of `.popover()` as done [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/567qr3mm/4/), it should work just fine. What do you think?